# apache ignite discovery connect to zookeeper using ssl connection

Tags: ignite

I am trying to use Zookeeper for node discovery with Apache Ignite.  I have configured Zookeeper to only accept SSL/TLS connections.  How do I provide Zookeeper keystore detail to Apache Ignite ZookeeperDiscoverySpi?  I have checked the documentation and source code of ignite-zookeeper.jar and I do not see any options to supply these details?  Should I be providing these details elsewhere in the ignite config?

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

1. replace inginite-zookeeper.jar dependency zookeeper-3.4.6.jar with latest zookeeper-3.5.x.jar for proper SSL/Netty support.
2. supply SSL config details as JVM arguments (no options for this in Ignize Spi API)